# iOS Swift - How can I upload video file to PHP script using POST method?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video, file-upload

The video file data is of type NSData and I would like to be able to post it to the PHP server. I know how to typical parameters like strings, integers, base64 encoded strings, etc. I'm just unsure of how to POST the video data. I would like the Swift code to be able to mimic the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="videoupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I already have the PHP code working on the server. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve the same result as the HTML posted above, but by using Swift for iOS? Also, I prefer not to use third party components from Github. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you'd prefer not to use a third party resource, you'll have to look into a few items. Specifically, `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest`, and either `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` (NSURLSession is a newer API and is suggested for use by Apple). Then it gets to the fun part. You'll have to look into how to build an HTTP body, which will contain all of your data and information on it. For example, here is a snippet of a project of mine that sends an image and a name to a PHP script, it shouldn't be hard to adapt to your needs.

```
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image-name\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("\(user).png".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: image/png\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Transfer-Encoding: application/octet-stream\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"\(user).png\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(imageData)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

Lastly you'll need to look into the `Content-Type` HTTP header. Typically multipart/form-data will do the job, but it's always good to know why that's so.

Good luck.